# VLOOK-up without N/A and 0 results (extraction from 2 sheets)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to create an if-vlookup that retrieves data from 2 sheets with following specs:

1. if the retrieve from the 1st sheet shows N/A and 0 results than vlookup from the 2nd sheet;
2. if the the 2nd vlookup retrieves N/A and 0 results than change them with blanks.

Comment: please try it and show us (with example), so we can help

Answer (score -1):

Use IFERROR to pass processing on a failed lookup.

```
=iferror(vlookup(a1, sheet1!A:B, 2, false), iferror(vlookup(a1, sheet2!A:B, 2, false), ""))
```

Comment: I have tried it but the "0" results still remain. Thank you !